# Calling a function from another .cpp file

Tags: c++, function, vcl

I am using C++ Builder and am creating a VCL Forms application.

Here is my code:

```
std::string returnStringFromUnicodeString(AnsiString str)
{
std::string s(str.c_str());
return s;
}
```

Currently I have this in the main.cpp file and can use this function from any other functions in this .cpp file.

My question is this: How can I call this function from another GUI form? I have included the .h of the main .cpp file but still have no luck.

Do I have to make it public or some other method?

Thanks

Comment: What in your code is putting a **Unicode** string in an `AnsiString`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your function in a header, and you need to place the implementain in another cpp file, not ine with a main in it, so no     int main     or    void main etc

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to put that helper function in separate header and cpp files, so that you can use it across your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
std::string returnStringFromUnicodeString(AnsiString str);
```

to your main.h file.

Answer (score 0):

A different way, is to add a prototype with extern in the form you want to use it:

```
extern std::string returnStringFromUnicodeString(AnsiString str);
```

But I think is better to use headers.